# PHP streamline add and remove array element

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is there a way in PHP or Laravel 5.2 to streamline the following:

1. iterate through array. In my example, a collection of industries
2. add an item. In my example In my example, 'app_id' and padded uuid
3. remove original item. In my case the original uuid element

**Ideal Outcome:**

Can I streamline `function paddUuids($item)` and `public function getIndustries()`

**Context (why do I want to do this):**

Using native uuid with CSS doesn't work as class and ID because the first character cannot be numeric so I need to add alpha prefix to uuid. Second, Angular 1.5 seems to struggles with Uuid (even as string) or Uuid with hyphens i.e. keep getting duplicate index error.

```
  class SegmentsController extends Controller
    {
        use UuidTrait;
        /**
         * @var Industry
         */
        protected $industry;

        /**
         * SegmentsController constructor.
         */
        public function __construct(Industry $industry)
        {
            $this->industry = $industry;
        }

        /**
         * Remove uuid hypens and add prefix to use with Angular and as CSS class
         * @param $item
         * @return mixed
         */
        function paddUuids($item)
        {
            $item['app_id'] = $this->paddUuid($item['uuid']);
            unset($item['uuid']);
            return $item;
        }

        /**
         * Return Iterate through industries
         * @return array
         */
        public function getIndustries()
        {
            return array_map (array($this, 'paddUuids'), $this->industry->get()->toArray() );
        }
    }
```